# What is the quota cost and id limit for listing videos via YouTube Data API?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am listing videos using the YouTube Data API:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list

In the documentation it states that this call incurs 1 unit of quota.
It also states that the "id" field is a comma-separated list of video IDs.

How many video IDs can be put in the "id" field?
Is the quota cost still just 1 no matter how many video IDs is in the "id" field?

Answer (score 1):

Quota cost is based upon the number of requests you make.  If you make a single call to [videos.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) its going to cost one point.

Adding ids does not effect the number of requests you are making its still just going to be one request.

As for the number of ids you can filter on.  The documentation doesn't state there is a limit.

> id string
> The id parameter specifies a comma-separated list of the YouTube video ID(s) for the resource(s) that are being retrieved. In a video resource, the id property specifies the video's ID.

Give it a try see how many you can add.  TBH the limit may be just by the limit of the size of the array on googles side.